# multiple lines of jsx and truthiness check

Tags: reactjs

I know the below works by testing the truthiness of message:

```
    {message && <div>This works</div>}
```

But how do I make it work with multiple lines of jsx?

```
    {message && <div>
      <span>{message}</span>
    </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to use parentheses:

```
    {message && (<div>
        <span>{message}</span>
      </div>
    )}
```